# How can I efficiently scrub Ruby's negative zero float?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, negative-number

In Ruby, `0.0 * -1 == -0.0`.

I have an application where I multiply a bunch of `Float` objects with `-1`, but I don't like the `-0.0` in the output, since it's confusing.

Is there a smart way of making `Float#to_s` output `0.0` instead of `-0.0`?

I'm completely fine with running every `Float` object through some kind of scrubber/helper method, but the following just tends to make me even more confused:

```
def clean_output(amount)
  if amount.zero?
    0.0
  else
    amount
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

To be more precise on what I'm looking for, I want a solution that I can run on a whole bunch of floats, some of which will be negative, some positive. The negative ones should remain negative unless they're negative zeroes, i.e. `-0.0`.

Examples:

```
clean_output(-0.0) #=>  0.0
clean_output(-3.0) #=> -3.0
clean_output(3.0)  #=>  3.0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the code you wrote confuses you then this ought to really bend your mind:

```
def clean_output(amount)
  amount.zero? && 0.0 || amount
end
```

With some proof:

```
irb(main):005:0> f = 0.0
=> 0.0
irb(main):006:0> f.zero? && 0.0 || f
=> 0.0
irb(main):007:0> f = -0.0
=> -0.0
irb(main):008:0> f.zero? && 0.0 || f
=> 0.0
irb(main):009:0> f=1.0
=> 1.0
irb(main):010:0> f.zero? && 0.0 || f
=> 1.0
```

I don't like using `nonzero?` because its use-case is a bit confused. It's part of Numeric but the docs show it used as part of Comparable with the `<=>` operator. Plus, I'd rather test for a zero condition for this purpose because it seems more straightforward.

And, though the OP's code might appear verbose, this is another of those cases where premature optimization doesn't pay off:

```
require 'benchmark'

def clean_output(amount)
  if amount.zero?
    0.0
  else
    amount
  end
end

def clean_output2(amount)
  amount.zero? && 0.0 || amount
end

def clean_output3(value)
  value + 0
end

class Numeric
  def clean_to_s
    (nonzero? || abs).to_s
  end
end


n = 5_000_000
Benchmark.bm(14) do |x|
  x.report( "clean_output:"  ) { n.times { a = clean_output(-0.0)  } }
  x.report( "clean_output2:" ) { n.times { a = clean_output2(-0.0) } }
  x.report( "clean_output3:" ) { n.times { a = clean_output3(-0.0) } }
  x.report( "clean_to_s:"    ) { n.times { a = 0.0.clean_to_s      } }
end
```

And the results:

```
ruby test.rb 
                    user     system      total        real
clean_output:   2.120000   0.000000   2.120000 (  2.127556)
clean_output2:  2.230000   0.000000   2.230000 (  2.222796)
clean_output3:  2.530000   0.000000   2.530000 (  2.534189)
clean_to_s:     7.200000   0.010000   7.210000 (  7.200648)

ruby test.rb 
                    user     system      total        real
clean_output:   2.120000   0.000000   2.120000 (  2.122890)
clean_output2:  2.200000   0.000000   2.200000 (  2.203456)
clean_output3:  2.540000   0.000000   2.540000 (  2.533085)
clean_to_s:     7.200000   0.010000   7.210000 (  7.204332)
```

---

I added a version without the `to_s`. These were run on my laptop, which is several years old, which is why the resulting times are higher than the previous tests:

```
require 'benchmark'

def clean_output(amount)
  if amount.zero?
    0.0
  else
    amount
  end
end

def clean_output2(amount)
  amount.zero? && 0.0 || amount
end

def clean_output3(value)
  value + 0
end

class Numeric
  def clean_to_s
    (nonzero? || abs).to_s
  end

  def clean_no_to_s
    nonzero? || abs
  end

end


n = 5_000_000
Benchmark.bm(14) do |x|
  x.report( "clean_output:"  ) { n.times { a = clean_output(-0.0)  } }
  x.report( "clean_output2:" ) { n.times { a = clean_output2(-0.0) } }
  x.report( "clean_output3:" ) { n.times { a = clean_output3(-0.0) } }
  x.report( "clean_to_s:"    ) { n.times { a = -0.0.clean_to_s     } }
  x.report( "clean_no_to_s:" ) { n.times { a = -0.0.clean_no_to_s  } }
end
```

And the results:

```
ruby test.rb 
                    user     system      total        real
clean_output:   3.030000   0.000000   3.030000 (  3.028541)
clean_output2:  2.990000   0.010000   3.000000 (  2.992095)
clean_output3:  3.610000   0.000000   3.610000 (  3.610988)
clean_to_s:     8.710000   0.010000   8.720000 (  8.718266)
clean_no_to_s:  5.170000   0.000000   5.170000 (  5.170987)

ruby test.rb 
                    user     system      total        real
clean_output:   3.050000   0.000000   3.050000 (  3.050175)
clean_output2:  3.010000   0.010000   3.020000 (  3.004055)
clean_output3:  3.520000   0.000000   3.520000 (  3.525969)
clean_to_s:     8.710000   0.000000   8.710000 (  8.710635)
clean_no_to_s:  5.140000   0.010000   5.150000 (  5.142462)
```

To sort out what was slowing down `non_zero?`:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 5_000_000
Benchmark.bm(9) do |x|
  x.report( "nonzero?:" ) { n.times { -0.0.nonzero? } }
  x.report( "abs:"      ) { n.times { -0.0.abs      } }
  x.report( "to_s:"     ) { n.times { -0.0.to_s     } }
end
```

With the results:

```
ruby test.rb 
               user     system      total        real
nonzero?:  2.750000   0.000000   2.750000 (  2.754931)
abs:       2.570000   0.010000   2.580000 (  2.569420)
to_s:      4.690000   0.000000   4.690000 (  4.687808)

ruby test.rb 
               user     system      total        real
nonzero?:  2.770000   0.000000   2.770000 (  2.767523)
abs:       2.570000   0.010000   2.580000 (  2.569757)
to_s:      4.670000   0.000000   4.670000 (  4.678333)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It's really informative. The benchmarks aren't really that relevant for my application, but it's very interesting to see that the clean_to_s is so much slower than the other solutions.

Comment: The difference won't be that big if you remove `to_s` call. If you're going to print that values it'll be called anyway, but in this benchmark it's called explicitly in `clean_to_s`. Though, `nonzero?` + `abs` is slower anyway most likely because it involves two method calls instead of one in other cases.

Comment: @KL-7, "The difference won't be that big if you remove to_s call." I added some more tests to see.

Answer (score 13):

There is actually a solution which does not require a condition.

```
def clean_output(value)
  value + 0
end
```

output:

```
> clean_output(3.0)
=> 3.0 
> clean_output(-3.0)
=> -3.0 
> clean_output(-0.0)
=> 0.0
```

I don't actually like this solution better than the one I accepted, because of lack of clarity. If I'd see this in a piece of code I didn't write myself, I'd wonder why you'd want to add zero to everything.

It does solve the problem though, so I thought I'd share it here anyway.

Comment: If people only ever used code they're familiar with, there wouldn't be much learning happening. Just saying..

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of anything better than that:

```
def clean_output(value)
  value.nonzero? || value.abs
end
```

but that's just a variation of your solution. Though, unlike yours this one doesn't change type of `value` (if, for example, you pass `-0` it'll return `0`). But looks like it's not important in your case.

If you're sure that'll make your code cleaner you can add method like that to `Numeric` class (that will make that method available for `Float`, `Fixnum`, and other numeric classes):

```
class Numeric
  def clean_to_s
    (nonzero? || abs).to_s
  end
end
```

and then use it:

```
-0.0.clean_to_s # => '0.0'
-3.0.clean_to_s # => '-3.0'
# same method for Fixnum's as a bonus
-0.clean_to_s   # => '0'
```

That will make easier to process an array of floats:

```
[-0.0, -3.0, 0.0, -0].map &:clean_to_s
# => ["0.0", "-3.0", "0.0", "0"]
```

Comment: Hm... and here I was assuming that Numeric#nonzero? was supposed to return a boolean value.

Comment: No, it returns object itself if it's not zero and `nil` otherwise. See [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F).

Comment: I did. I guess I'm just a bit naive in thinking that methods ending in `?` should return an actual boolean, but it's obviously very usable this way.

Answer (score 0):

simply just check whether answer is **zero** then apply **abs** to the value. It will convert -0.0 into 0.0

```
fl_num = -0.0
fl_num = fl_num.abs

fl_num = 0.0
```

Comment: Sure, but that won't do for any other value. Since I have a whole bunch of floats, some of them may be actual negative numbers, and in that case they should stay that way. `-3.0.abs` is not `-3.0`. I'm looking for something that only affects a negative zero (`-0.0`).

Comment: @Martin okay, but you can check if **value** is zero then apply else it will remain same negative number, right ?

Comment: You mean `if f1_num.zero?; f1_num.abs; else; f1_num; end`? That's basically the same solution as I wrote in the question... I guess one part of my question is whether you can solve this without an `if`.

Comment: you could extend floats to have a function that'll just return zero if it's a zero.

Comment: had a look on whole documentation and also never think like you did. :) So, can't find any solution for that bcoz as per IEEE standards there are two zeros, +0 and -0. Hence, condition is required.

Comment: And by extension: `1.0/0.0 => Infinity` and `1.0/-0.0 => -Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the intent of this code is a little clearer and at least in Ruby 1.9.3 it's slightly faster than @the Tin Man's

```
def clean_output4(amount)
  amount.zero? ? 0.0 : amount
end

                     user     system      total        real
clean_output:    0.860000   0.000000   0.860000 (  0.859446)
clean_output4:   0.830000   0.000000   0.830000 (  0.837595)
```